# При а = 1, b = -1, c = -2 выводится -1.000000 и 2.000000. Как убрать ненужные ноли после запятой, не нарушая правильности ответов?

Tags: python

При а = 1, b = -1, c = -2 выводится -1.000000 и 2.000000.

Как убрать ненужные ноли после запятой, не нарушая правильности ответов?

```
    import math
    a = float(input())
    b = float(input())
    c = float(input())
    D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
    if D > 0:
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
        if x1 > x2:
            print(('{0:.6f}'.format(x2)), ('{0:.6f}'.format(x1)), end='')
        elif x1 < x2:
            print(('{0:.6f}'.format(x1)), ('{0:.6f}'.format(x2)), end='')
    elif D == 0:
        x1 = -b / (2 * a)
        if x1 % math.floor(x1) == 0:
            print(int(x1))
    elif D < 0:
        print('')
```

Comment: а какой именно вам ответ нужен? вы же сами поставили формат выводить до 6 знака!!!

Answer (score 2):

используйте округление до 6 знака:

```
round(x, 6)
```

чем просто вывод с точностью в 6 знака... всегда

```
{0:.6f}'.format(x1)
```

код:

```
D = b ** 2 - 4 * a * c
if D > 0:
    x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a)
    if x1 > x2:
        print(round(x2, 6), round(x1, 6), end='')
    elif x1 < x2:
        print(round(x1, 6), round(x2, 6), end='')
elif D == 0:
    x1 = -b / (2 * a)
    if x1 % math.floor(x1) == 0:
        print(int(x1))
elif D < 0:
    print('')
```

**P.S.**

кстати гораздо проще вместо

```
if x1 > x2:
    print(round(x2, 6), round(x1, 6), end='')
elif x1 < x2:
    print(round(x1, 6), round(x2, 6), end='')
```

выводить так:

```
print(round(min(x1, x2), 6), round(max(x1, x2), 6), end='')
```

**P.P.S.**

ну и вы понимаете, что при `a = 0` у вас `D = 0` и происходит деление на 0?

при полном решении квадратного уравнения надо учесть что

1. оно может быть не квадратным, а линейным (`a = 0`)
2. оно может содержать бесконечное кол-во решений (`a = 0, b = 0`)

**P.P.P.S.**

вы же понимаете, что в этом коде:

```
elif D == 0:
    x1 = -b / (2 * a)
    if x1 % math.floor(x1) == 0:
        print(int(x1))
```

вывод результата будет только в 1 случае - если решение является целым числом?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Не подскажите как вообще убрать ноли после запятой, если они там не нужны?

Comment: `('%f' % x).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')` - например так (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440692/formatting-floats-without-trailing-zeros)

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вы сами устанавливаете формат вывода, напишите `'{0:.0f}'.format(x2)` вместо `'{0:.6f}'.format(x2)`

Comment: Да, но при ответе, требующий знаки после запятой, будет без них, а значит и ответ неправильный. Ведь так?

Comment: теперь понял в чем дело, это похоже на то, что вам нужно)
https://coderoad.ru/24142141/Удаление-нулей-из-числовой-строки-в-Python#24142420

Comment: Огромное спасибо!